# Changing background color of only one from two lists using button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made 2 lists using ul, li tags and a button. Using JavaScript I want to be able to change background colour of every li tag from black to white, and in reverse, but only in one list. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add you HTML and CSS code for a `minimal reproducable code snippet`. Best even include a drawing of your wanted layout. Mostlikely you dont even need JS. It proberly could be done with pure HTML and CSS with the use of `classes` and/or `nth-child(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here's one which always selects the first list. Substitute in your desired colors.

```js
function swap(){
  document.querySelectorAll("ul:first-of-type li").forEach(x => x.style.backgroundColor = (x.style.backgroundColor == "black" ? "white" : "black"));
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>

<button id="swap" onclick="swap()">Button</button>
```

Comment: if that is what the user tries to do, then css `body ul:first-child { background-color: red; }` would be the easier and better solution.

Comment: I don't disagree with you at all, but he wants a javascript solution

Answer (score 1):

you can, also, toggle a class from which you invert the colors , it will be a much shorter code and easier to update, you can also use a function() expecting a variable, so you can use it many times.

example

```js
function invert(x) {
  document.querySelector(x).classList.toggle("invert")
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  background: gray;
}

li {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

.invert {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="invert('ul:first-of-type ')">invert first ul</button>
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul><button type="button" onclick="invert('ul:last-of-type ')">invert last ul</button>
```